# Qt -Show result of select top

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I've trying to show result of my query. first of all , if connection to server is ok, it have to show "*connected*" and otherwise it should show "*not connected*".it shows me "connected". after that, I've trying to show last 3 names but it shows me "*cannot select*".

```
    #include <QCoreApplication>
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QtSql/QSql>
    #include<QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
    #include <QtSql/QSqlDriver>
    #include<QtSql/QSqlQuery>
    #include<QDebug>
    #include<QtSql/QSqlError>
    #include<QSqlDatabase>
    #include<QSqlTableModel>
    bool createConnection(), createConnection_second();
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication app (argc,argv);
        if (!createConnection() ){
            qDebug()<<"not connected";
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
        qDebug()<<"connected";
        QSqlQuery qry;

        qry.exec("SELECT TOP 3 name FROM student");
        while (qry.next()){
            QString name = qry.value(0).toString();
            qDebug()<<"name:"<<name;
        }
        if(!qry.exec())
            qDebug()<<"cannot select";
        else
            qDebug()<<"select";
        return 0;
 }

        return app.exec();
    }
    bool createConnection(){
        QSqlDatabase db= QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
        db.setHostName("localhost");
        db.setUserName("root");
        db.setDatabaseName("connection_qt");
        db.setPassword("");
        if (!db.open()){
            qDebug()<<"Database error occured";
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems there are a couple of issues that you don't understand fully, the most important of which will answer your question.

---

SQL, as a query language, is not completely standardised, there are slightly different dialects among the various database engines available.

While almost all database engines understand the most frequently used clauses like `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`, some database engines don't understand the less-frequently used clauses.

This is the problem that you have unfortunately discovered, you are trying to get a subset of a query by using the `TOP` clause.

The `TOP` clause is not universally understood, this is part of the T-SQL dialect, used by Microsoft database engines in Access or SQL Server.

Unfortunately, MySQL and Oracle databases use different clauses to achieve the same thing: the `LIMIT` clause for MySQL, and `ROWNUM` for Oracle.

The `LIMIT` clause must be put at the very end of the SQL statement and can have either one or two parameters. It's syntax is:

`LIMIT [offset,] rowcount`

Since you are using a MySQL database engine in your question, you need to modify your SQL query to be the following:

SELECT name FROM student LIMIT 3

(If you don't put the `offset` value in, it is assumed that the offset is 0)

---

There is a second issue that I noticed in your code. It is not the cause of your problem but it might become a problem in the future, seeing as you appear to want to have two connections open.

If you use the statement:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
```

You are not creating a new database connection, you are accessing the default database connection.

If you want to open a new connection the same way, somewhere else in your program, you are going to reset the default connection and replace it with your new connection details.

To be able to have more than one connection open at the same time, you need to give your different connections unique names.

```
QSqlDatabase db1 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "connection1");
QSqlDatabase db2 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", "connection2");
```

Be aware though, connections persist between function calls, you can access connections that have already been created (and opened) using

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("connection1");
```

but if you're finished with your connection, remember to close the connection and remove it from the global connection list:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("connection1");
db.close();
QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("connection1");
db = QSqlDatabase::database("connection2");
db.close();
QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("connection2");
```

Be careful though, you MUST close the connection before you remove it or else you'll cause a resource leak.

Look in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html) for a more details explanation on how to use these functions.

EDIT:

I forgot to add, if you are using named connections, you must pass the database object to the `QSqlQuery` object in order to associate the query with that particular named connection, otherwise, the query will attempt to use the default database connection.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("connection1");
QSqlQuery query(db);
```

Comment: Thank you for yor answer

Answer (score -2):

Maybe that's why because your object **QSqlDatabase db** is created on stack in function so, when function is end Object **db is disappears**. Try create this object as pointer outside ...

in main function

```
main()
{

QSqlDatabase *db = new  QSqlDatabase();
// your setings db

     QApplication app (argc,argv);

        QSqlQuery qry;
        qry.exec("SELECT TOP 3 name FROM student");
        while (qry.next()){
            QString name = qry.value(0).toString();
            qDebug()<<"name:"<<name;
        }

     app.exec();

}
```

I write on hand so I can not tell you wheter is worked but I whant to show only conception. Conception is heap not stack into function

Comment: The default database connection will not close unless instructed to. It is a global database connection so it doesn't matter if a local copy of it is opened on the stack and then the function ends, destroying the local copy.